# toString() method prints nulls

Tags: java, tostring

My toString method is not giving the desired result.

What I want is something like:
[Submarine, 5, false]

What I get is:
[null, 0, false]

My class looks like this

```
public class Ship {

private String name;
private int size;
private boolean isDestroyed;

public Ship(String n, int s, boolean d) {

    n = this.name;
    s = this.size;
    d = this.isDestroyed;
}

public String toString() {
    String output = "";
    output = "[" + name + ", " + size + ", " + isDestroyed + "]";
    return output;

}
}
```

I've searched for something similar, and others' problems were that they did not use the this keyword. Since I use it, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Assignment is right to left.

Comment: @user2740689 Hint: your `toString()`'s implementation can be simplified to the single line `return "[" + name + ", " + size + ", " + isDestroyed + "]";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = this.name;
```

should be

```
this.name = n;
```

same for the other field variables

Comment: Youre assigning the instance variables (which default to `null`, `0` and `false` respectively) to the local variables instead of the other way around. Read: [Assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You  assigning value in wrong way.

```
this.name= n;
this.size= s;
this.isDestroyed= d;
```

Or for name.

```
this.name="XYZ";
```

you can't store valriable into value

```
"YYZ"=thi.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = this.name;
```

means assign the value of "this.name" to "n". But the value of "this.name" is null, so you get nothing.